# How are these RC values calculated in this buck converter?

Tags: power-supply, buck

Buck converter: LTC3824

The datasheet says:

> VC (Pin 4): The Output of the voltage error amplifier gm and the
>   control signal of the current mode PWM control loop. Switching starts
>   at 0.7V, and higher VC corresponds to higher inductor current. When VC
>   is pulled below 25mV, the LTC3824 goes into micropower shutdown.

[image: schem]

I can't find any values in the datasheet to calculate the R1 and C1 values. How does the Vc value change with inductor current? The inductor current goes to the output, not to ground...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is your compensation network, it is very critical to the power supplies stability.

Since you say there is nothing in the datasheet regarding the component selection, I checked Linears design tools.  It turns out there isn't a model for the LTC3824 in LTpowerCAD .  While checking, I noticed that Linear recommends you use the LTC3864 for new designs, rather than the LTC3824.  While there is probably an LTspice model for the LTC3824, you could spend hours trying to pinpoint the proper component values by simulating all day.

Honestly, without support in component selection between their simulation tools and the datasheet for the LTC3824, I would urge you to move to their recommended replacement IC, the LTC3864.  [Here is the datasheet.](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3864fa.pdf)  The LTC3864 does have an LTpowerCAD model, and I'd be shocked if they didn't have an LTspice model.  It will be MUCH easier to design around.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the [dataheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3824fg.pdf) these components form a low pass on the output of the current controller. They are components that are not meant to be included in the design process. The values of these components are selected by LT to keep the current control loop stable while still have a fast enough transient response. I would just use the values suggested by LT and if I run into stability problems during prototyping, I'd give them a call.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they don't give you formulas to calculate it because it depends on the system you're trying to control. It is there just to slow down the signal so the PWM comparator won't oscillate. If the output voltage of GM is changing too fast to lead to stable output control then increase the resistor or capacitor, or both.

The Vc pin is a voltage that is compared with a sawtooth wave to generate the PWM for control. You want the comparison signal to not make large rapid movements. Adding the RC will slow down this signal.